# How to know client URL name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created web-api to provide service like pin-code, Bank IFSC Code and so on, from my website named as `http://www.ajaxserver.com`

My all api is hosted on my site and my all client access using my site.
web api code is

```
    [Route("api/GetURLName/")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetURLName(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri ;
    }
```

One of my client website name is `http://www.clientwebsite.online`

client is used jquery to retrieve info like below code.

```
     $('#btnTestCore').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ajaxserver.com/api/GetURLName/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
             },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('failed.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Output comes:

```
"http://ajaxserver.com/api/GetURLName/".
```

Need Output:

```
"http://clientwebsite.online/api/GetURLName/"
```

Comment: what you see is the expected behavior as you are returning the Request url ( which is your site). Have you tried RequestReferrer

Comment: I have tweaked the urls to avoid the post looking spammy

Comment: Unable to use RequestReferrer , runtime error shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the server of the ajax request knows; the "site" is itself, so `http://www.ajaxserver.com`. You *could* try to look at the referrer, but... that isn't reliable across all browsers and protocols.

So you have two choices:

- have the client API *tell you* the calling site - note that it could trivially be spoofed by the client
- do some non-trivial proxy (etc) configuration such that the ajax server's site responds on the client domain

Note that  `http://clientwebsite.online/api/GetURLName/` was **not** the actual URL and is not going to come from anywhere by itself.

Comment: I could not understand your answer. Can you write some lines for me to get my outputs?

Comment: @SujeetKumarSingh "Can you write some lines for me to get my outputs?" no, because  what you want is based on a faulty premise; what you want **is not just a  case of changing a few lines**. It involves changing your approach. I have already described 2 different options for doing that.

Comment: I know, I am going in wrong way,  But I can say frankly,  
I could not understand your above approach...

Comment: string clientDomain = string.Empty;
    clientDomain = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host;

Comment: string clientDomain = string.Empty;
    clientDomain = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host; these lines are not working....

Comment: Is your client not supposed to send some authentication info (or a unique token or combination of them to identify the client) from which server will be able to identify which client is making the call ?

Answer (score 1):

You could append the output to your AJAX request:

```
$('#btnTestCore').click(function () {
       var urlname = encodeURI("http://clientwebsite.online/api/GetURLName/")
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://ajaxserver.com/api/GetURLName?urlname=' + urlname,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
             },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('failed.');
            }
        });
    });
```

You will then, of course, have to read that querystring in your webAPI code